# The difference between "there are" and "I have" in terms of implication

Tags: phrase-usage

> There is a mountain very close to my house. It's only five minutes' walk. That's why *I have* many unusual birds coming to my yard all year around.

If I change the last sentence to "*There are many unusual birds coming to my yard*," is there any difference in the implication? I think this is a very basic question, but I still wonder which I should use, "*I have*" or "*there are*".

Comment: Well since you have the plural *birds* it wouldn't be "*there is*", it would be "*there are*". As for a difference in implication, the "*I have*" emphasizes your connection to the birds in your yard, while "*there are*" is a mere statement of fact that the birds exist in your yard.

Comment: Unrelated to the question you're asking, "It's only five minutes' walk" is incorrect English. The idiomatic expression would be "It's only a five minute walk."

Comment: @Daniel That is arguably incorrect, by many people still say it. Technically, in either case "five" and "minutes" should be hyphenated.

Comment: @Jay Yes, you are right. And I know that it is arguably incorrect. I just wrote it that way because, in my experience, that is the idiomatic way of saying it, whereas the way it is written in the question would never be accepted as correct.

Comment: *There is* doesn't work.  *There's* does, but it's informal.  In formal Standard English, *there are* is required.

Comment: @Daniel and Jay Thank you for the comments. THe phrase you pointed out always bothers me. But my textbook says that I can say either "a five-minute walk" or "five minutes' walk". I'm getting a bit confused.

Comment: @snailboat There is doesn't work.  There's does. What does it mean?  Is this about my sentence or in geneal?

Comment: @tennisgirl I was referring to the original version of the question which said *"there is"*.  Here is what I was trying to say: **"There is many unusual birds"* is wrong.  In formal Standard English, *"There are many unusual birds"* is better.  The weird part is this: informally, you can say *"There's many unusual birds"*, even though you can't say **"There is many unusual birds"*.

Comment: @snailboat I got it.  I just wanted to make sure, because every comment you wrote here is a good opportunity for me to learn. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*I have* many birds coming to my yard" makes sense because we are talking about *my* yard. You couldn't say, "*I have* many birds coming to *his* yard."

If you change the sentence the way you have suggested, there is a change in meaning. Saying "There are many birds coming..." means that they are on the way right now, perhaps for a big bird party that is happening in an hour. It wouldn't fit with your first sentence which doesn't explain why there would be birds flying to your yard right now in particular.

If you want to change the sentence to not use "I have," you could say "That's why many unusual birds come to my yard all year around."